# Reference to Developer Story when Editing User Profiles on all Sites except Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

When editing your user profile on any site **except Stack Overflow**, there is still a mention to the developer story in the Private Information section, next to the Full Name text box:

[image: Developer story]

[Since Developer Stories have been removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story), this message should also. This image was taken from my Arqade profile, and my Super User and Pets profile also still show this message, so it seems to be present on all sites.  Stack Overflow does not have this message.

Comment: The message should now be modified to say that this affects the user's name on any SO for Teams sites the user is a member of. (Teams sites show real names)

Comment: @sonic - except that name is decoupled from the "real name" on site.

Comment: @Catija It used to be synced at one point; when was this changed? I remember modifying my real name on public SO and it changing my screen name on Teams. As far as I can tell, it's still correct in that if a user joins a new Team, their initial display name there will be copied from the real name field.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Yes, we will pull the name from the field for convenience but picking something else doesn't override what you have on site. [They're separate databases.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368334/joining-a-team-forces-my-stack-overflow-identity-to-match-my-real-name)

Comment: @Catija Ah, it's been that way since 2019. I haven't touched any profile settings on my Teams profile since joining the Charcoal team in 2018, when it used to work as I described it previously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops! We had this warning behind a feature flag that was only flipped on Stack Overflow on accident. We've flipped it across the network so it shouldn't be displayed anymore.